# How is it possible for Centre and the like to blacklist Ethereum addresses when they themselves are not miners/validators?

Tags: transactions, mining, addresses

There is no shortage of [the news](https://coingeek.com/usdc-blacklists-an-address-for-the-first-time/) on stablecoin censorship, in particular blacklisting of Ethereum addresses:

> Tether has been blacklisting Ethereum addresses that hold USDT for a couple of years now—this year alone,
> Tether has blacklisted 24 addresses that hold a total of $5.51 million USDT in summation.
> [...]
> Tether has blacklisted a total of 39 out of the 1.47 million Tether addresses that exist,
> which represents a total of 0.00002% of all tether addresses.
> When a tether address is blacklisted, it can’t **send, receive,** or redeem USDT.

Assuming that the said stablecoin issuers are not miners/validators, how are they able to do censor sending and receiving? Does such censorship involve also [NFTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token), Eth, and other erc-20 tokens? Could similar censorship be done by MakerDao?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They own the contracts.

For example, one of the [Tether contracts](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7) is named `BlackList`. This contains a mapping:

```
mapping (address => bool) public isBlackListed;
```

...which can be updated by the owners using `addBlackList()`.

When an address is added to the blacklist, that address can no longer use its Tether balance.

Comment: Does MakerDao own like contacts and could they practice similar censorship with respect to DAI?