# Can a particular account be blacklisted by the contractowner so that this account can't any longer own a ERC-721 token they bought earlier?

Tags: erc-721, nft

Can the contract deployer of an NFT collection blacklist a particular address?
Much the same way [as Tether contracts can be updated](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93352) with `addBlackList()`.
For example, is it doable for [World of Women](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93352) to censor me
a month after buying one of [their NFTs](https://opensea.io/collection/world-of-women-nft) (so that I no longer can have their NFT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blacklisting is possible simply if the contract has such functionality. Since the contract handles token transfers, a token can also include functionality which restricts transfers, according to some logic.

In theory, since the contract also has the ledger of ownerships, if the contract has such functionality, your NFT could even be removed. But I've never seen such functionality in any non-scam project.

Comment: Let's say I bought an NFT from a project that was audited and it is known that their contract is without the said functionality. Can such functionality be added later by them to the contract so that my account is censored? Or are such contracts immutable in that matter?

Comment: All contracts are always immutable. But various architectural patterns exist where multiple contracts work together and some contracts may be switched to a newer version. This is often called upgradable contracts. If there is no such functionality built-in, then there is no way to add extra functionality afterwards.